# What is the best way to migration from shopify to magento2.3.5

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, migration, data-migration

I want to **migrate** one **Shopify** website to **Magento 2.3.5** I need some suggestions, What will be the best way to migrate in less time with perfect efficiency.

- On my Shopify website, there are 50000 products, 5000 customers, 10000 orders, etc.
- I want the same product and category URLs after migration.

After migration in Magento 2.3.5, I want the below things. Please suggest for that.

- **use elastic search**
- **configure varnish cache**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

better option is to install magento 2 import/export extension.

then export data from shopify to csv files, and fix formatting in google sheets for example.

then import:

- products
- customers
- orders

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, the answer above is really the only way to go about it. Export to csv and import into M2.

Obviously coming from shopify you have not had to worry about hosting. If you are using M2 community 2.3.5 you will need a good reputable hosting company. Preferably that specialised in optimisation for M2. Elastic search just needs to be installed. As when you upgrade to 2.4 it is mandatory.

Varnish configuration can be tricky on M2 sites depending on the kind of customisations you might make to the front end theme. I've had it play up with the mini cart before for example. It really does improve the performance of your M2 site though if you get it right.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Besides the methods mentioned above, you can also consider using our automated migration tool to save your time manually configure the migration and eliminate the risk of missing data or errors in the process. That way, it will take only about 22 hours to migrate a store of your size from Shopify to Magento while ensure perfect accuracy.